# Admin SDK permissions have changed, script now generates privileges error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a project that runs every day to aggregate information from a central calendar, including the email address of each person who contributed an event, and then use the `Admin SDK` to retrieve the name of each user based on email address. [Code on Github](https://github.com/superstrong/who-is-out/blob/master/events.gs#L109)

Some time around January 20, 2017, it stopped worked due to failed privileges with no changes to the code or user. This is the function:

```
function getUserName(email) {
    var result = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email, { fields: 'name' });
    var fullname = result.name.fullName;
    return fullname;
}
```

Specifically, the `AdminDirectory.Users.get` call no longer works. The user running this function has `User Management Admin` privileges, though it doesn't work even if I upgrade it to full admin.

What changed? How do I get it to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I just tried it as a domain administrator and it worked fine. Can you try using the Api explorer and see if you can get any query to work?

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/admin/directory_v1/directory.users.get

Comment: It's working for me again, too. Puzzled, but content. Thanks for your time!